# Modify a BQ dataset through Google Sheets

Tags: google-bigquery, google-drive-api

I have a big dataset stored in BQ. I was wondering whether there is a way to pull in slices of it into Google Sheets and then update it (for example overwrite some values).

I can bring it in using the BQ connector but I cannot modify the dataset, only slice and dice it.

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to pull data into Google Drive? You can slice data into Cloud Storage and modify !

Comment: The goal is to have the data presented to a marketing team (hence the need for Google Sheets) in a tabular form so they can filter, review, and if necessary, modify some values. And these modified values trickle back to BQ.

Comment: do you want a complete automation ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "automation". Think of it as follows: there is a big dataset in BQ. I need to be able to view certain slices of it after filtering (no grouping). Then, if I change a value in the Sheets the same corresponding value changes in BQ.

Comment: I mean, the whole process do you want to be completely "automated" without any manual interference !

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223649/discussion-between-skm-and-denim).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

1. Write a SELECT query with necessary filtering criteria
2. Run the SELECT query
3. Click on "SAVE RESULTS"
4. Save the Output into Google Sheets

[image]

5. Allow business team to make changes
6. Create an External Table pointing to Google Sheets
7. Query the External Table and perform UPDATE on changes to main table

Comment: This is not an automated process. If you don't like this solution, please let me know, so that I will delete my post !

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me think about your solution.

Comment: Just want to add that there is [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE][1] statement now for you to create the external table.


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_external_table_statement

Comment: @YunZhang: thank you for your continuous efforts for the community !

Comment: @SKM 
the issue with your suggested approach is that the filtering cannot be done by the business team. 

The solution I've implemented is to offload my data into the Sheets & create a BQ table that uses the sheet as a source. Any update on the sheets is reflected in BQ. The issue with this approach is that Sheets are struggling to respond to filtering due to the size of the data.